# Expose Dart functions to javascript

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I'm a bit of a newb to dart, and trying to get my feet wet by writing some library functions in it.

While I've had no problem calling javascript functions from dart, I'd love to be able to call dart functions from javascript, but so far, I'm not having much like.

For example, I'd love to be able to expose some basic functions from dart, for example like so:

```dart
main() {
  String foo() {
    return "bar!";
  }

  js.scoped(() {
    js.context.foo = foo;
  });
}
```

and then be able to call them from javascript, like so:

```dart
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    alert("foo() = " + foo());
  }
</script>
```

Is something like this even possible?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174508/is-there-a-better-way-to-make-a-method-of-a-dart-class-callable-from-js-with-the

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No problem ! see [Calling Dart from JavaScript](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/#calling-dart-from-javascript).

In your case :

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;
main() {
  String foo() {
    return "bar!";
  }

  js.context['foo'] = foo;
}
```

Comment: and suddenly, it does not work: claims "There is no such setter 'foo' in 'Proxy'" ...

Comment: yes :)  first update of js went to 0.19 which continued to not work. After an edit restart, and a second update, I got 0.20 and it is all good again. Thanks again!

Comment: Callback is not mentioned in the linked document 'Calling Dart from JavaScript'. Was it removed?

Comment: Yes the answer was outdated.

Comment: What is the recommended way now ?

Comment: The answer had been updated. What you see is the current way to do.

Comment: You can just assign "js.context.foo=foo", you don't need the [] index syntax unless you are getting from the proxy and want a null instead of an error.

Comment: `package:js` should not be used (see https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15795#c15 for more detail). The sample code is for `dart:js`.

Answer (score 4):

In Dart 1.20 I had to add `allowInterop()`

```
import 'dart:js' as js;
main() {
  String foo() {
    return "bar!";
  }

  js.context['foo'] = allowInterop(foo);
}
```

Comment: this works well in native dart (dartium) but not in js compiled version (chrome, ff, ie..). Please check this [screenshot](http://data.itpro.cz/dart_js.png). When I remove allowInterop, it works even in js compilled version. I am using Dart 1.19.1. Is it something that was fixed in 1.20?

Comment: Seemed to work for me in Chrome and Dartium. I'll check again and report back.

Comment: Checked again and I can confirm that it's working in Dartium and Chrome.

Comment: Thank you for verification. I have tried to create empty sample polymer project, containing only code in screenshot above and it does not work for me with use of allowInterop (works in Dartium but not in IE, FF, Chrome). I have tested in in multiple browsers on multiple computers. You can test it yourself if you want to: http://data.itpro.cz/dart_allowinterop. When you press F12 in Chrome and type: foo() you will get an error, if you type foo2() it writes "bar2!"

Answer (score 2):

In Dart 2.3.0 I had to tweak the solution just a bit for `allowInterop` to play nice.

```
    import 'dart:js' as js;
    main() {
      String foo() {
        return "bar!";
      }

      js.context['foo'] = js.allowInterop(foo);
    }
```