# Convert Dart (no dependencies) library to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dart, flutter, nativescript

I have a Dart repo that I'm working on with a friend. I plan on consuming this library in Flutter. My friend, who also needs to use this, intends to use NativeScript.

Is there a way to generate JavaScript from our Dart library? The Dart library has no dependencies (other than the Dart SDK).

If there isn't an alternative, is there a suggestion for a better way to share our code between Flutter and NativeScript?

There exists another post, [Using dart to create a javascript library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723500/using-dart-to-create-a-javascript-library), that is similar to mine. However, that post was asked over 4 years ago. I imagine there may exist new developments for this Dart to JavaScript problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using dart to create a javascript library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723500/using-dart-to-create-a-javascript-library)

Comment: I was hoping that, after 4 years, further developments or insights into how to approach this problem may exist.

Comment: Apparently, there was some experimental work on that, but keep in mind that it will be impossible to tree-shake the resulting JS code, since you don't know which APIs will never be called in your library.