# Is there a better way to make a method of a Dart class callable from JS with the new js 0.6.0 package?

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

**index.html (head)**

```
<script>
  var callDartMethod = function(dartObject) {
    return dartObject.fullName();
  }
</script>
```

**index.dart**

```
import 'package:js/js.dart';

@Js() // about to being changed to @JS
external String callDartMethod(p);

main() {
  final p = Person.create(firstName: 'Günter', lastName: 'Zöchbauer');
  print(callDartMethod(p)); // indirect call from JS
  // print(p.fullName()); // call from Dart directly
}

@Js() // about to being changed to @JS
class Person {
  external String get firstName;
  external set firstName(String firstName);

  external String get lastName;
  external set lastName(String lastName);

  external Function get fullName;
  external set fullName(Function function);

  external factory Person({String firstName, String lastName});

  static Person create({String firstName, String lastName}) =>
      new Person(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName)
        // works but feels a bit cumbersome
        ..fullName = allowInteropCaptureThis(fullNameImpl);

  static String fullNameImpl(self) => '${self.firstName} ${self.lastName}';
}
```

Comment: Hi, Gunter. I wonder if the `fullNameJs` getter in your example is a mistake? Should it be `external Function get fullName;` ?

Comment: I guess so. Seems I changed names midway but not everywhere. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Thanks for example, I think it will help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

`pkg/js` is currently focused on letting a Dart app consume JavaScript libraries.

We want to make it easier to export APIs written in Dart to JavaScript consumers, but that will come later.

Comment: Do the new `js_interop` packages change this answer?