# Convert Dart object to JS object

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I would like to use JS interop to expose a set of functions/objects coded in dart.

I know how to use js-interop to share variables with JS scripts. But I have a requirement : I can't edit dart classes as they are coming from an external library without JS dependency.

And while I know it's possible to do something like :

```
@anonymous
@JS()
class Config {
    external bool get value;

    external factory Config({bool value});

    factory Config.fromExternalLib(ExternalConfig config) {
        return new Config(value: config.value);
    }
}
```

I'd like to avoid that, as it requires to duplicate every classes.

Is there any way to convert any dart object to JS object without modifying or forking the class ?

Comment: Looks like a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174508/is-there-a-better-way-to-make-a-method-of-a-dart-class-callable-from-js-with-the

Comment: The "no" doesn't really help sadly. Do you know any workaround ? Such as converting to `Map`, then have a primitive to JS converter ; or a code-gen to generate the above class ?

Comment: The code in my question should give some hints what can be done. Haven't used it much since myself and don't remember details.

Comment: You can convert maps to JS objects, but not Dart class instances.